# Iterate an array, n items at a time

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

that I'd like to iterate 3 at a time, which produces

```
1,2,3  and  4,5,6  and  7,8,9   and   0
```

What's the best way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You are looking for [#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

```
data.each_slice(3) {|slice| ... }
```

Comment: That does it. Missed checking enumerable, and was only checking array methods. Thanks.

Comment: Always remember to check Enumerable when dealing with Hashes or Arrays - most of the good stuff is hidden away in there. :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Oddly enough, I did look in Enumerable but totally missed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Use [.each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0].each_slice(3) {|a| p a}
```