# Take 3 posts at a time in Liquid (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, liquid

This might be exceedingly obvious, but I'm making a Jekyll blog from scratch, and I'm using Shopify's [Liquid](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid).

Say I have a collection of posts:

```
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5, post6, post7, post8, post9, post10
```

I'm trying to render three posts at a time into a `<div>`. So it would look something like this:

```
<div>
    post1
    post2
    post3
</div>
<div>
    post4
    post5
    post6
</div>
<div>
    post7
    post8
    post9
</div>
<div>
    post10
</div>
```

How would I accomplish this in Liquid? 
Something like ruby's [splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869614/iterate-an-array-n-items-at-a-time) would seem to suffice, but I could not find how to do this in Liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for p in site.posts %}
   {% assign counter = forloop.index | modulo:3 %}
   {% if counter == 1 %}<div>{% endif %}
   <h3>{{ p.title }}</h3>
   {% if forloop.last or counter == 0 %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```